# Approximate LaTeX's beamerarticle package in Pandoc markdown

Tags: slideshow, pandoc, article

I would like to write beamer slides in Pandoc markdown and generate matching lecture notes with longer, explanatory text. But I can't figure out the logic.

If I were to do this in LaTeX, then I would use the `beamerarticle` package in the `article` class version *or* the `ignorenonframetext` option in the `beamer` class version. With this setup I can add notes *between* frames and quickly generate slides for the screen and lecture notes for the desks. Here is an example. Toggling the comments on the first three lines should illustrate this.

```
% \documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{beamerarticle}
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{This is my first slide}
This is my first slides content.

\[ PV = FV / (1 + r)^t \]
\end{frame}

This is the longer text that I want to appear in the notes/handouts, but not in the beamer.

\begin{frame}{This is the second slide}
Short content.
\end{frame}

Longer content.

\end{document}
```

But this doesn't work with Pandoc slides because I can't write *between* the frames because the frames are only split by `---`.

I tried to write my own command `gobble` and it works fine when I compile to pdf, but not when I compile to beamer. Here is an example. Toggling the comments on the `newcommand` lines only provides the desired result for the `article` class. The `beamer` class won't compile.

```
% Chapter 1
% Richard
% May 15, 2015

\newcommand{\gobble}[1]{}
<!-- \newcommand{\gobble}[1]{#1} -->

---

# This is my first slide

This is my first slides content. Test.

$$ PV = FV / (1 + r)^t $$

\gobble{This is the longer text that I want to appear in the notes/handouts, but not in the beamer}

---

# This is the second slide

Short content.
```

Is there a way to approximate `beamerarticle` and `ignorenonframetext` in Pandoc markdown?

Comment: This is material for a good feature request to submit to Pandoc developers. You should ***[ask for + discuss potential current workarounds here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss)*** and ***[submit a feature request for proper support here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/new)***.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle - Thanks! I found the right way to achieve this (I think) and will post a solution below. Thanks for the prod.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to wrap "notes" that you want to appear in the handout, but not in the slides, in `<div class="notes"></div>`. When you compile to beamer with something like `pandoc -o temp.pdf -t beamer temp.md` anything wrapped in this `div` tag will be wrapped in `\notes{}` in the intermediate \LaTeX\ file and not appear in basic beamer slide.

```
% Chapter 1
% Richard
% May 15, 2015

# This is my first slide

This is my first slides content. Test.

$$ PV = FV / (1 + r)^t $$

<div = class="notes">
This is the longer text that I want to appear in the notes/handouts, but not in the beamer
</div>

# This is the second slide {.allowframebreaks}

Short content.

\framebreak

Second part of second slide.
```

Another trick is to specify frame breaks with `\framebreak` and include `{.allowframebreaks}` at the slide level. If you compile the article version to \LaTeX\ rather than directly to pdf and define `\framebreak` to be an empty macro with

```
\def \framebreak {}
```

then you can get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible work around is using the `--slide-level` flag.  Pandoc does not transfer content [above the slide level](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#structuring-the-slide-show).  You can manually set the slide level and the insert a higher level header like

```
% Title
% Me
% today

#

This appears only in the supporting material.

## This is my first slide

This is my first slides content. Test.

$$ PV = FV / (1 + r)^t $$

#

This is the longer text that I want to appear in the notes/handouts, but
not in the beamer

## This is the second slide

Short content.
```

Running with `pandoc --to=beamer -o mwe.pdf --slide-level=2 mwe.md` generates the slide show without the content under level 1 headers. The downside is you get empty subsection headers in the document.  If you're okay with not having section header slides, you can set the `section-titles` to `false` in the metadata block.  I wound up post-processing the generated LaTeX to strip out the empty headers and running LaTeX separately from Pandoc.

Comment: Just a comment that this no longer works as of Pandoc 2.17. See https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4317. Everything under a heading that is not in a frame is now added to a frame.